# How to make my own web comic site like xkcd?

Tags: looking-for-a-script

If you all are nerds like me then you are aware of [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/).  If I wanted to go about creating my own web comic with a website layout similar to this one, then what would you recommend?  Drupal (if so, also refer me to any non-default modules that I would need), WordPress, straight up html?

Comment: I believe that this question would be better suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think he's looking for a platform and not a development stack (straight up html would be a nightmare).  Perhaps superuser would be the place to go.

Comment: I think it's fine here.

Comment: I was migrated from serverfault, but since I didn't yet have a profile here, I don't own this question even though I wrote it.  That stinks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out [ComicPress](http://comicpress.org/), based on on Wordpress.

Answer (score 5):

the simpler is [Blogger](http://www.blogger.com/), that you can custom to have the same layout.

Simpler because:

- free (not like freedom)
- easy to use
- easy to custom (behavior, template, CSS...)
- no installation
- no worry about hosting
- direct integration with Picasa for your pictures
- you can use your own domain name
- Useful widgets

Answer (score 0):

You might consider [Tumblr](https://www.tumblr.com/). Tumblr has most of what Blogger offers, plus it has a 'post-to-Twitter' feature. Also, Tumblr allows you to schedule when posts should be published (though to be fair, you can do this with [Blogger](http://www.blogger.com/) too).